# Delete feature draw selected does not update map

Tags: openlayers, javascript, draw-interaction

I have code to draw lines, polygons, point and circle in Openlayers. I can select a design and delete it. When I run this code to delete, it deletes the drawing from the map, unless the drawing was the last one to be drawn.

ol.control.Bar, ol.control.Toggle e ol.controlButton can be seen on ol-ext: [example controls draw ol-ext](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.undoredo.html)

```
// Main control bar - controle de desenho
var control_bar_draw = new ol.control.Bar();


/* Nested toobar with one control activated at once */
var nested_bar_draw = new ol.control.Bar ({ toggleOne: true, group:true });
control_bar_draw.addControl (nested_bar_draw);

// Add selection tool:
//  1- a toggle control with a select interaction
//  2- an option bar to delete / get information on the selected feature
var sbar = new ol.control.Bar();
sbar.addControl (new ol.control.Button({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>',
    title: "Delete",
    handleClick: function() {
        var features = button_draw_select.getInteraction().getFeatures();
        if (!features.getLength()) alert("Select an object first...");
        else alert(features.getLength()+" object(s) deleted.");
        alert('features.getLength' + features.getLength())
        var lastFeature = features[features.length - 1];

        for (var i=0, f; f=features.item(i); i++) {
            vector_layer.getSource().removeFeature(f);
                
        }
        button_draw_select.getInteraction().getFeatures().clear();
    }
}));


// Add selection tool (a toggle control with a select interaction)
var button_draw_select = new ol.control.Toggle({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-hand-pointer-o"></i>',
    className: "select",
    title: "Seleciona desenho",
    bar: sbar,
    interaction: new ol.interaction.Select({
        layers: [vector_layer],
        style: selectedStyle,
        condition: ol.events.condition.singleClick,
    }),
    //active:true,
});
nested_bar_draw.addControl(button_draw_select)

    
// Add tool draw point
var interaction_point = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type: 'Point',
    source: vector_layer.getSource()
});

    
var button_draw_point = new ol.control.Toggle({
    html: '<i class="fa fa-map-marker" ></i>', 
    className: "edit",
    title: 'Ponto',
    interaction: interaction_point,
});
nested_bar_draw.addControl(button_draw_point)
    
//add tool draw line
var interaction_line = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type: 'LineString',
    source: vector_layer.getSource()
});


var button_draw_line = new ol.control.Toggle({
    html: '<i class="fg-polyline"></i>', 
    className: "edit",
    title: 'Linha',
    interaction: interaction_line,      
});
nested_bar_draw.addControl(button_draw_line)

//add tool draw circle
var interaction_circle = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type: 'Circle',
    source: vector_layer.getSource()
});
    

var button_draw_circle = new ol.control.Toggle({
    html: '<i class="fg-circle"></i>',
    className: "edit",
    title: 'Círculo',
    interaction: interaction_circle,
  
});
nested_bar_draw.addControl(button_draw_circle)

//add tool draw polygon
var interaction_polygon = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type: 'Polygon',
    source: vector_layer.getSource()
});


var button_draw_polygon = new ol.control.Toggle({
    html: '<i class="fg-polygon-o"></i>', 
    className: "edit",
    title: 'Polígono',
    interaction: interaction_polygon,
  
});
nested_bar_draw.addControl(button_draw_polygon)


function clearAll(){
    vector_layer.getSource().clear();
}   


// Add buttons to the bar
var buttons_bar = new ol.control.Bar({ 
    group: true,
    controls: [
        new ol.control.Button({
            html:'<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
            title: 'Excluir desenho(s)',
            handleClick: function() {
                clearAll();
                alert('Excluído ')
            }
        }),
    ]
});
control_bar_draw.addControl(buttons_bar);


// Add a snap
map.addInteraction(new ol.interaction.Snap({ 
    source: vector_layer.getSource() 
}));
```

Comment: Yes, it's just a question when selecting a drawing and I delete, if that drawing was the last one to be drawn, it doesn't delete from the map, just after clicking another part. The same happens if you try to delete everything at once: it only updates the map after clicking on another part of the map or button.

Answer (score 0):

Loops using live arrays or collections often cause problems, for example

```
    for (var i=0, f; f=features.item(i); i++) {
        vector_layer.getSource().removeFeature(f);
    }
```

if you remove a feature from the source it may also be removed from the live collection of features selected from that source, changing the index of the remaining features in the collection.  Using a snapshot such as

```
    var features = button_draw_select.getInteraction().getFeatures().getArray().slice();
    for (var i=0, len = features.length; i < len - 1; i++) {
        vector_layer.getSource().removeFeature(features[i]);
    }
```

might be a safer way of removing all but the last selected feature

Comment: If I have a single feature selected, with this code, I don't even enter the for: `for (var i=0, len = features.length; i < len - 1; i++)`. Changing to `i < len`, enter for, delete, but not 'erase from map'. If I have recognized characteristics, both are not two characteristics, but one 'erases it from the map'. I'm using openlayers 5.